# Windows hotkeys are too slow to use

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, process

I use some scripts to copy some strings which I frequently use. I assigned hotkeys to them, with which I can copy those string with keyboard shortcuts.

The problem is that Windows is taking way too long to run those scripts. From another Super User question ([Slow Windows Desktop Keyboard Shortcuts](https://superuser.com/questions/426947/slow-windows-desktop-keyboard-shortcuts)), I understand that Windows queries all the existing windows if they have that hotkey before executing.

In my case, those windows definitely wouldn't exist because they close as soon as they copy strings to the clipboard. How can I disable Windows checking all existing windows for hotkey matches?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "those windows wouldn't definitely exist" or why other programs wouldn't still slow down your shortcuts, try killing some running programs & check again. Or try using another 3rd party shortcut program

Comment: The link you cited https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-slow-to-execute/67afb465-e97f-4264-8ae3-84960b797dd3 provides a solution, disabling SUPERFETCH at boot. Have you tried it? If not satisfactory, please click [edit] and let us know why it doesn't work for you.